# C function to read only numeric values

Tags: c, integer

I'm learning C and as exercise I'm trying to implement a custom function to parse a input from user and return successfully only if the input is a number.
These are my files, how could I improve it?

**my_main.c**

```
#include "my_utils.h"

void main() {
    int a;
    char num[10]; 
    size_t l = sizeof(num); 
    a = read_int(&a, num, l, message);
    printf("The number is %d", a);
}
```

**my_utils.h**

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int read_int(int *a, char *num, size_t l, const char *message) {
    int err;
    size_t length;
    do {
        if (message)
            printf(message);
        fgets(num, l, stdin);
        length = strlen(num);
        err = 0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (!isdigit(num[i]) && num[i] != '\n' && num[i] != '\0' && num[i] != EOF) {
                if(i == 0 && num[i] == '-') //-123 is a valid input, 1-23 is not
                    continue;
                printf("Only numbers allowed. Try again\n");
                err = 1;
                if (length > 0 && num[length - 1] != '\n') { //stdin flush
                    int c;
                    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
                        ;
                }
                break;
            }
            if (num[i] == '\n' && num[i + 1] == '\0') {
            break;
            }
        }
    } while (err != 0);
    *a = atoi(num);
    if (length > 0 && num[length - 1] != '\n') {
        int c;
        while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF)
            ;
    }
    return *a;
}
```

Maybe (surely?) is overkill to handle only a `int` input, but I'd like to know if there are best practice or whatever a newbie should know to improve. Thanks

Comment: Show us the whole program, please, including `#include`s.

Comment: This code does not compile, not even with ancient C89.

Comment: @J_H fixed. Is it clearer now?

Comment: @404NameNotFound why is that? I made my test for a hour before posting it here. If you were referring to the lack of `#include` , it is now fixed (and they were obviously present in my original code)

Comment: In the file `my_main.c`, you are using the undeclared identifier `message`. Therefore, your posted code does not compile. Please post code that actually compiles.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel you're right, I forgot to copy a line, but it's a simple `char message[]="insert a number";`

Comment: Next time you want to ask a question about code, check it by copying the code back from the question into a file (or online compiler like https://godbolt.org/) and making sure it compiles (and demonstrates what you want it to, if you're asking about a bug or performance issue instead of code review.)

Comment: The first thing I object to is the "specification": "custom function to parse a input from user and return successfully only if the input is a number". The use of `fgets` indicates that you expect a single line. This should be part of the specification. It is also not very general: Neither `atoi` nor `scanf` demand that. It is in my opinion better to not expect newlines unless they are specifically necessary for an application, and instead simply use word boundaries with *any* whitespace. Managing interactive user interfaces are a layer on top of that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Definition of function `main`

The definition of the function `main` should start with

```
int main( void )
```

instead of:

```
void main()
```

The return type of `void` is illegal in ISO C, unless your platform happens to support it as an extension. However, even if your platform does support `void`, using it is generally not recommended, because otherwise, your code may not be portable to other platforms.

See the following Stack Overflow question for further information:

[What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/204476/12149471)

## Add include guards to header files

You should generally add include guards to header files, for example

```
#ifndef MY_UTILS_H_INCLUDED
#define MY_UTILS_H_INCLUDED
```

at the start of the file, and then

```
#endif
```

at the end of the file.

This will ensure that the header file will only be included once per translation unit (`.c` source code file). Otherwise, you may get errors if the same header file is included more than once in the same translation unit. See the following question for further information:

[Why are #ifndef and #define used in C++ header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1653958/12149471)

On some platforms, you can simply write `#pragma once` at the start of the file, in order to achieve the same effect. However, this is not guaranteed to work on all platforms. See the following question for further information:

[#pragma once vs include guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143936/12149471)

## Functions should be defined in source files, not header files

In your posted code, you are defining the function `read_int` in a header file. However, this is generally a bad idea, because if this header is included by more than one translation unit (`.c` source file), then your program will likely fail to compile/link, due to violating the [one-definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern#One_definition_rule).

For this reason, functions should generally be defined in `.c` source files and not in header files. Header files should generally only contain function **declarations**, but not **definitions**.

I therefore suggest that you move the definition of the function `read_int` to a file with the name `my_utils.c` and that you compile that file together with `my_main.c`. The file `my_utils.h` should only contain a declaration of the function `read_int`:

```
int read_int(int *a, char *num, size_t l, const char *message);
```

## Don't call `printf` using a format string from an unknown source

The line

```
printf(message);
```

is dangerous, because `message` is interpreted as a pointer to the format string. This string is supplied by the caller and it is unclear whether it may contain `%` characters, which have a special meaning in a `printf` format string. For example, if the format string happens to contain `%s`, then the function `printf` will attempt to de-reference the non-existant pointer parameter, which will likely cause the program to crash.

For this reason, it would be safer to write

```
printf( "%s", message );
```

or

```
fputs( message, stdout );
```

instead. That way, if the string happens to contain a `%`, this character will not have any special meaning; it will be printed like any other character.

## Always check the return value of `fgets`

It is possible for the function `fgets` to fail, for example due to an I/O error or if the user triggers end-of-file on the terminal/console (for example by pressing <kbd>CTRL-D</kbd> on Linux or <kbd>CTRL-Z</kbd> on Windows). Therefore, you should generally always check the return value of `fgets` and, if an error occurred, act accordingly.

If `fgets` returns `NULL`, then `num` is not guaranteed to point to a null-terminated string. If you call

```
length = strlen(num);
```

and `num` does not point to a null-terminated string, then your program will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (i.e. your program may crash).

## The parameters of the function `read_int` are unnecessarily cumbersome

You have defined the function `read_int` with the following parameters and return type:

```
int read_int(int *a, char *num, size_t l, const char *message)
```

The function is passing back the result value both as a return value and via the pointer parameter `a`. In other words, the function is passing the same value back to the calling function twice, although once would be sufficient. I recommend that you only use the return value. That way, you can eliminate the parameter `a`.

Also, there is no reason for the function `read_int` to use a memory buffer supplied by the caller. If the function uses its own memory buffer instead, then you can also eliminate the parameters `num` and `l`.

## Use `strtol` instead of `atoi`

I recommend that you use the function [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) instead of [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi). This has the following advantages:

1. The function `strtol` will tell you if the value is outside of the representable range of the integer data type, whereas the function `atoi` will invoke undefined behavior in that case.
2. The function `strtol` will tell you how many characters were successfully converted, by passing an optional pointer to the first character that was not parsed. That way, it is no longer necessary for you to call `isdigit` on every single character in order to determine whether the input is valid. Also, this will automatically allow the digits to be prefixed with `+` or `-` and you will no longer have to handle these cases yourself.

## Code example

Here is the definition of my function `get_int_from_user`, which I have been using regularly and is intended to do the same thing as your function `read_int`. It follows all the advice mentioned above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

//This function will attempt to read one integer from the user. If
//the input is invalid, it will automatically reprompt the user,
//until the input is valid.
int get_int_from_user( const char *prompt )
{
    //loop forever until user enters a valid number
    for (;;)
    {
        char buffer[1024], *p;
        long l;

        //prompt user for input
        fputs( prompt, stdout );

        //get one line of input from input stream
        if ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin ) == NULL )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable input error!\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        //make sure that entire line was read in (i.e. that
        //the buffer was not too small)
        if ( strchr( buffer, '\n' ) == NULL && !feof( stdin ) )
        {
            int c;

            printf( "Line input was too long!\n" );

            //discard remainder of line
            do
            {
                c = getchar();

                if ( c == EOF )
                {
                    fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

            } while ( c != '\n' );

            continue;
        }

        //attempt to convert string to number
        errno = 0;
        l = strtol( buffer, &p, 10 );
        if ( p == buffer )
        {
            printf( "Error converting string to number!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that number is representable as an "int"
        if ( errno == ERANGE || l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX )
        {
            printf( "Number out of range error!\n" );
            continue;
        }

        //make sure that remainder of line contains only whitespace,
        //so that input such as "6abc" gets rejected
        for ( ; *p != '\0'; p++ )
        {
            if ( !isspace( (unsigned char)*p ) )
            {
                printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );

                //cannot use `continue` here, because that would go to
                //the next iteration of the innermost loop, but we
                //want to go to the next iteration of the outer loop
                goto continue_outer_loop;
            }
        }

        return l;

    continue_outer_loop:
        continue;
    }
}
```

This code was copied from [this answer of mine to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73915292/12149471). See that answer for further explanation of my code.

Comment: I understand we don't have C++ exceptions here, and there's a desire to keep the Public API simple. But yikes! Couple of places where we can trash the whole process, and the comments at top don't warn of that. I would not e.g. expect `$ echo -n 123 | ./a.out` to die hard where `$ echo 123 | ./a.out` succeeds -- [POLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment). I mean, _my_ text editors all take care to append trailing newline at EOF, but an astounding number of text files on github follow a laxer set of rules.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explaination. I owe you a beer :)

Comment: One additional comment on style, which I think would be worth adding. It is a bad idea to use a single lowercase L as a variable name, since it is easily mistaken for the number 1.

Comment: Andreas Wenzel,  Why `if ( c == EOF ) { fprintf( stderr, "Unrecoverable error reading from input!\n" );  exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }` when consuming the rest of the line? I'd expect reading the rest of the line to act the same if `'\n'` or end-of-file encountered.

Comment: @chux: If a stream error or end-of-file occurs on the input stream after the input is rejected, then the program will be unable prompt the user for new input. Therefore, the function will be unable to return an `int`, so it exits the program instead with an error code indicating failure. However, you are correct that I could probably simply ignore this and wait for `fgets` to fail in the next loop iteration. But this has the disadvantage that if the user enters end-of-file in the terminal, then my code would possibly not notice, if the stream state of end-of-file is not "sticky".

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Reasonable approach.  BTW: End-of-file is sticky in that `fgets()` will return `NULL` if end-of-file flag set, not so with error flag.

Comment: @chux: As far as I can tell, the ISO C11 standard states in §7.21.7.1 that with the `fgetc` function, end-of-file is sticky. However, it does not state this in §7.21.7.2 with the `fgets` function. On the other hand, §7.21.3 ¶11 states the following: `"The byte input functions read characters from the stream as if by successive calls to the fgetc function."` Since `fgets` is a "byte input function", I guess that means that with `fgets`, end-of-file must also be sticky. [...]

Comment: @chux: [...] However, using Microsoft Visual Studio on Microsoft Windows, if I call `getchar()` and then provide as input end-of-file by pressing `CTRL-Z` and then `ENTER`, then `getchar()` will return `EOF`. However, if I call `fgets` immediately afterwards, it will not immediately return `NULL` to indicate end-of-file, but will instead wait for more user input and return non-`NULL` if that input is valid. I guess MS Visual Studio does not comply with the ISO C standard in this respect.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I suspect it is MS [_extending_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embrace,_extend,_and_extinguish) the functionality.

Comment: The `errno == ERANGE` test seems redundant at first view; however it covers a couple of corner cases on systems where `LONG_MIN == INT_MIN` and/or `LONG_MAX == INT_MAX`.  Well done on the robustness there!

Comment: @TobySpeight: `errno == ERANGE` covers the case of the user input not being representable as a `long`. `l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX` covers the case of the user input being representable as a `long`, but not as an `int`. Both of these checks are necessary.

Comment: So you only caught that case by accident?  Remember that `strtol()` is a "saturating" function which returns `LONG_MIN` or `LONG_MAX` when the input is out of range; on most systems (where `int` is narrower than `long`) that would be caught by the `l < INT_MIN || l > INT_MAX` test.

Comment: @Andreas Wenzel, Alternative to `goto`: `while (isspace( (unsigned char)*p )) p++; if (*p != '\0') { printf( "Unexpected input encountered!\n" );  continue; }`

Comment: @Andreas - judging from the comments here, you might want to [ask](/questions/ask) for a review yourself...

Comment: @TobySpeight: Ah, yes, you are correct that `errno == ERANGE` is redundant on systems on which `LONG_MAX > INT_MAX`. I didn't think of that. However, as you pointed out, it is better to not make the assumption that `LONG_MAX > INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux, did you read my comment?  I was specifically calling that out as good practice that's easily overlooked.

Comment: @chux: Yes, that is a nice way of avoiding the `goto`. I didn't think of that. Thanks.

Comment: @chux, that's part of an exchange - see [earlier comment](/a/286243/75307#comment569983_286243).

Answer (score 4):

Late to the review

**Why 10 in `char num[10];`?**

If trying to accommodate all 32-bit `int`, including `"-2147483648\n"`, the input buffer needs to be larger - at least 13.  Even larger for error detection.

As it is good to

- oversize the input buffer to accept reasonable variants like `"   -00001234567890   \n"`,
- oversize the input buffer to detect extra junk,
- scale the buffer to the size of `int`,
- avoid naked magic numbers,
- avoid huge buffers like `char num[1000000]` for something that only needs a few dozen,

... consider

```
#define INT_BUF_SIZE (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)  // About 3x min size needed
char num[INT_BUF_SIZE];
```

For a common 32-bit `int`, this will be 32 to handle input like `"-2147483648\n"` along with some leading spaces/zeros and trailing white-spaces.

True that "valid" input could be `"000...million more zeros... 000123"`, yet at some point such excessively long input should be considered hostile and not valid.

I recommend using a 2-3x buffer of the the longest standard input.

Answer (score 3):

### `<ctype.h>` functions accept `int`

The functions in `<ctype.h>`, such as `isdigit()` accept only positive integers and the constant `EOF` as inputs.  On platforms where `char` is a signed type, converting directly to `int` can be Undefined behaviour.  Convert to `unsigned char` first, using a cast or by reading through a `unsigned char*`.

### `l` is a terrible name for a variable

`l` is easily confused with `1` (or `I`).  Prefer more descriptive names, particularly in public interfaces.

Comment: Only for the pedantic: `isdigit(num[i])` should be `isdigit(((unsigned char *)num)[i])` to work properly on non-2's compliment implementations rather than `isdigit((unsigned char) num[i])`.  With C23, the point [is moot](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x54vjpp).

Comment: The other way around, I think - on non-2s-complement platforms, we need to convert the _value_ to unsigned, rather than reinterpreting the bit pattern as unsigned.  That's because `fgets()` stores into `char*` as if by a sequence of `*p++ = fgetc()`.  So we need to retrieve the same way.

Comment: Might be a good [so] question if you still care about C17...

Comment: I'd say it is more like `*((unsigned char*)p)++ = fgetc()` to avoid implementation behavior. If we use `is...((unsigned char) num[i]))` we fold -0 and +0 into 0 before applying the function, losing distinctiveness.  Note that `str...()` act as-if the characters are `unsigned char`, even is `char` is _signed_, so -0 is not a _null character_ there.   IIRC,  non-2's complement implementations tended to have a _unsigned_ `char`, negating the issue.  And with C23, [what does it matter, its in the past](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dZfGTL2PY3E).